# Stuttering Mesh in perspective display viewport

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

I was working on modelling this piece for a necklace so it was already small in size but when I switch it to perspective the faces start to stutter and spasm like it’s Z-fighting.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like the mesh faces are pointing at different directions. I assume you tried the *recalculate normals* command?

Comment: Hey there and welcome. May i ask if i am just seeing things or are there faces inside the ring (second picture), is that just from the glitch or are there faces segmenting the ring? If so, you should remove them, as those *can* and *will* cause problems. Concerning the other issue, **try** to resize the object, in object mode, press "S" followed by typing in 10 and confirming with enter. You can also **try** to reduce the minimal "[Clip Start](https://imgur.com/whhaTPC)" found in the right sidebar opened with "N" while in the 3D-Viewport.

Comment: i think i may have found the solution thanks to the help here. I adjusted the clip start and that seemingly solved it. The value it was at beforehand was 0.000001 m and I don’t think that may have resorted in a glitch because if I adjusted it by dragging it like a slider then its lowers it can get is 0.001. 
To cross off the other suggestions
The normal are facing the right way, scaling did not solve anything and there is nothing inside the ring